# How do I unlink OneDrive using settings on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive, windows-live

I log in to my laptop with my gmail account but I cannot unlink the integrated OneDrive to access my existing onedrive account (user ID is an @live.com account).  When I right-click the task bar and select settings, the option to unlink is not there.

[image]

Comment: The user account either local or domain must be linked to a Microsoft Account to use the Microsoft OneDrive client.  OneDrive is basically integrated into Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The account you use for Windows MUST be the same as the one you use for OneDrive.